# Can't Navigate to another page in iphone while button click is working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

```
UIViewController *loginPage = [[[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPageViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:loginPage animated:YES];
```

With this part of code I want to navigate to another page. My button click is working fine, and showing text in level.

There is a class named landingpageviewcontroller another class LoginPageViewController. I want to push LoginPageViewController on a button click action from landingpageviewcontroller. Would you post a sample code for it?

Comment: Check your code you not put @ in your code.....initWithNibName here...

Comment: Why are you declaring `UIViewController *loginPage` for instance of `LoginPageViewController`? Also is `[self navigationController]` equal to `nil`?

Comment: There is a class named landingpageviewcontroller another class loginpageviewcontroller ....i want to push loginpageviewcontroller on a button click action from landingpageviewcontroller..can you post a sample code for it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self presentViewController:loginPage animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In exchange for

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:loginPage animated:YES];
```

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
TabsViewController *hello=[[TabsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TabsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:hello animated:YES];
    [hello release];
```

Change it according to you & check.

Answer (score 0):

```
LoginPageViewController  *loginPage = [[[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName@"LoginPageViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
[self navigationController pushViewController:loginPage animated:YES];
[loginPage release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

LandingPageViewController.m class

```
 #import"LoginPageViewController.h" //must import .h file

@implementation LandingPageViewController

-(IBAction)onLoginClick:(id)sender
{

    LoginPageViewController *loginController = [[[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPageViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginController animated:YES];


}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  LoginPageViewController *loginPage = [[[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPageViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]autorelease];
  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:loginPage animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LoginPageViewController  *move = [[LoginPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName@"LoginPageViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:move animated:YES];
[move release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one really helpful to you.

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

you may try this one.View Controller Store into stack .you can directly give yourviewcontroller value.

Like if 1st ViewController to go then place 0.
if 2nd ViewController to go then place 1.
if 3rd ViewController to go then place 2.